# Toldas las firmas aparecen al final de del correo

Tags: outlook

mi duda es la siguiente, tengo una firma en mi correo, pero cada vez que respondo o reenvió el correo las firmas se van acumulando todas en el final de el correo, me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para que esto no suceda y que las firmas aparezcan en el pie de cada correo y no todas juntas al final así como lo e visto a otras personas, de ante mano gracias

Answer (score 0):

puedes configurar para que respuestas o reenvios no le ponga firma.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]